# Как использовать тэги нескольких кнопок одного контроллера для изменения значения одного элемента на другом?

Tags: swift, button, tag

Ребята! Не могу найти нигде, как реализовать нужную мне задачу. Есть несколько кнопок на одном экране и один label на другом. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на разные кнопки текст менялся в этом одном label? Создала переменные с нужными мне значениями, а как теперь это связать?

Есть решения в пределах одного экрана, а как быть с двумя?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
var firstText = ""
var secondText = ""
var thirdText = ""

@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdButton: UIButton!
```

//здесь некоторые вычисления, из которых получаем строковое значение чисел
// дальше передача по segue в переменные на втором контроллере

второй контроллер

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
var firstLabelText = ""
var secondLabelText = ""
var thirdLabelText = ""

@IBOutlet weak var FirstLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    FirstLabel.text = firstLabelText
```

и вот как теперь сделать, чтобы нажимая на вторую кнопку этот текст принимал значение второй переменной, а при нажатии на третью - соответственно значение третьей переменной?

Всё что похоже было на мою задачу здесь попробовала применить, не то. Смутно понимаю, что надо как-то создать тэги этим кнопкам и передать их с первого на второй, создать условие, при котором присвоение значение происходит после проверки условия типа if button.tag = 1 или 2 или 3, тогда текст = переменная 1, 2 или 3. А как это программно делается? Хэлп! Сейчас смотрю уже второе видео из курсов по swiftи там пока ни сном ни духом о тэгах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу можно решить и без применения тегов, просто присваивая значение переменной, в которой будет храниться значение в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, затем передавать это значение во второй контроллер путем присваивания значения публичной переменной во втором контроллере

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdButton: UIButton!
    
    var selectedButtonText = ""
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch segue.destination {

        case let destination as SecondViewController:
            destination.labelText = selectedButtonText
        
        default:
            break
            
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender {
            
        case firstButton:
            selectedButtonText = "1"
            
        case secondButton:
            selectedButtonText = "2"
            
        case thirdButton:
            selectedButtonText = "3"
            
        default:
            break
            
        }
    }
    
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
    
    var labelText = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        firstLabel.text = labelText
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Мы так с Вами всё приложение напишем . Всё работает, только почему-то если в одном случае переменная одна и та же, её получается дважды в разные лэйблы передать нельзя? Но это уже другой вопрос. Вот как у Вас всё так легко укладывается? Как учиться, чтобы всё это откладывалось в голове?))))) Спасибо за помощь! Осталось совсем чуть-чуть! Всего парочка головоломок решить осталось! 

Comment: @КатаринаМалова пожалуйста, все приходит с опытом